# How do jobs queued for a long period affect performance?

Tags: php, laravel, events, queue, delay

I need to extend an existing Laravel web store with some kind of event handling. Examples of tasks include:

- If a user has registered, but hasn't purchased anything in X time, email them;
- If a user has spent X money in Y time, notify admin;
- If a user has visited page X for Y times, email them;

For this task I believe [Laravel Queues/Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#delayed-dispatching) are the right tool, possibly in combination with [Laravel Events](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events). What I would like to know is:

1. Is there a longest delay between a trigger and an action? I assume this depends on a driver, so which driver has longest delay times?
2. How would a delay of, let's say, a month or three months, affect overall app performance? Is this method considered best to handle delayed actions? Are there any alternatives to my idea?

Comment: The longer a job is queued the heavier it gets. Make sure you poor some reinforced concrete under the server if you expect it to hold many long queued jobs.

Comment: What is wrong with a CRON job that queries these cases once a day/week/month

Comment: @RiggsFolly honestly I'm not sure how to implement this using only Cron. Specifically, how do I use cron to send an email to a user who's been registered for 1 month, but hasn't bought anything? Also, the client specified that they need to be able to later add/modify events and actions taken.